# GitHub is painfully slow on Safari (macOS Sierra 10.12)

Tags: macos, github, safari, safari-extension, macos-sierra

After update to macOS Sierra 10.12, It became impossible to use GitHub.

Safari acts painfully slow on that. I've tried to clean cache with CleanMyMac 3, removed all extension (not disabled), and disabled all plugins for GitHub website (I actually have only 2 of them: Unity Plater and Adobe Manage).

Google does not give me any hints on what can be the problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: I have Safari on 10.12 and don't see this issue :\  Try installing another browser, and check to see if you have the same issue?  Do you have the same issue with other sites? I just have a hard time believing that a specific web app would load slowly due to a browser or OS update-- but I can't say for certain

Comment: Chrome works flawesly

Comment: Facing the same issue. Actually we're not alone https://twitter.com/nikitonsky/status/783589241561419776

Comment: @retgoat i hope github team will be aware soon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not about Apple or Github. All simple — roskomnadzor has blocked digicert's verification service `ocsp.digicert.com`. I believe you're from Russia that's why you're facing that issue.

There are several ways to solve that issue:

1. Use Chrome/Firefox/Any you want
2. Turn of SSL verification in Safari
3. Update your `/etc/hosts` with the next line: `72.21.91.29 ocsp.digicert.com`

I choose last one. Now all working fust fine.

You could find details [here](http://www.shortcut.ru/2016/10/03/when-in-doubt-use-sniffer/) and [here](https://geektimes.ru/post/281292/) Links only in russian.

Comment: Hmm, my problem is disappeared somehow on my laptop, I didn't test in my home Mac yet. Upvoted in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thank's a lot @s1ddok!

Comment: weird thing, I'm from Kyiv, Ukraine, and I faced the same issue.

Comment: Indeed... But what can I say?

Comment: Same issue in Spain.

Comment: Same issue from US, but only when looking at large MRs (that modify/add lots of files/lines).